# laravel mime validation in working while validating pgf

Tags: php, laravel

```php
$request=>validation([
  file'=>['required','mimes:pdf','max:22000']
]);
```

I tried validating PDF, but it still give me this error

> The file must be a file of type: pdf.

even when it is PDF.

Comment: You can try with a full mime type `mimetypes:application/pdf`

Comment: now getting The file must be a file of type: application/pdf.

Comment: do you try with another pdf file?

Comment: Make sure your `form` has an attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` use `multipart/form-data` when your `form` includes any `<input type="file">` elements